# First Site on Web! Getting -> Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fatal-error, shared-hosting

I ran the code on my development server and everything worked fine. FTP'd the files to my website this morning and anytime I make the webpage do a request to the database to either retrieve or send information, it gives me the error

> Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/

What is going on?

I have my `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` sitting in the root with my `index.php`.

I have allowed for extensions such as `pdo.so`, `pdo_sqlite.so`, `pdo_mysql.so` and `sqlite.so`.

I just really have no clue. I am using a shared server on godaddy. If anyone is familiar with the problem, please provide a list of solutions and I'll try every single one of them out. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you first check if PDO is loaded at all. Easiest is to execute this trivial but helpful script: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`...

Answer (score -1):

the solution is rather simple.

1. Google for `godaddy php.ini`
2. Navigate to the very first link called [PHP.INI/USER.INI: NOT TAKING EFFECT](https://www.godaddy.com/help/phpiniuserini-not-taking-effect-5647)
3. Follow instructions.

A note for the future readers in case information on the linked page gets expired (which means any info I might have copy-pasted here gets obsoleted as well): just start from the item No. 1.

Answer (score -1):

Below are the things you should check in order to correct the issue. The first thing we should check is to see if the server has the PDO extensions enabled.

Run the command below via SSH:

> php -m

You will then be presented with a list of modules currently installed in php, listed alphabetically. Look for PDO in the list. If it exists, then the module is installed. Ensure they are being called in the `php.ini` file

Somewhere in the `php.ini` file you should see the following:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

On Windows the addition needs to be

```
extension=pdo.dll
extension=pdo_mysql.dll
```

Let me know if you face any query regarding this.

Thanks!